# Solidworks EPDM Implementation in ASP.Net Core Web-App

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, solidworks

Someone can explain how i can Access the Vault from Solidworks in my ASp.Net Core 6 Web-Application?

i already create a Project with Identity fileupload/download and many more features. I got a Databasetable with all filenames and locations in the Vault i want to view my PDF files from Solidworks-Vault in webbrowser by accessing the files from this code:

FileController:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileFromFileSystem(int id)
    {

        var file = await context.FilesOnFileSystem.Where(x => x.FileId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (file == null) return null;
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file.FilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        return File(memory, file.FileType, file.Name + file.Extension);
    }
```

File Model:

```
public abstract class FileModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string UploadedBy { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Bereitgestellt am")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

If i go to the file with link like : http://localhost/File/DownloadFileFromFileSystem/1
i got a Error like :

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\SWVault\Draws\machines\mechanic\000021\DW064247-00.PDF' is denied.
```

The Path "C:/SWVault" is the Vault from Solidworks its installed in Explorer from Windows

i cant access the Path without type my Login Data in this window:

[Here the Login Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HPTB.png)

How i can my Controller access the Folder?

Comment: The Solidworks need which login information?

Comment: Solidworks PDM FileExplorer https://help.solidworks.com/2021/English/EnterprisePDM/FileExplorer/t_Logging_in.htm